# Alternative way to centre a button over an image without using position absolute, top and left

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I have come across an issue with my custom template in mailchimp.

I use absolute positions with top and left and transform to centre a button over an image. Now this works fine when I preview it, but when I send a test email on Gmail, these values are not there when I inspect, meaning the button is not in the centre.

I did some research and gmail does not like some of those attributes like absolute, top, left, transform etc, so what my question is that is there a workaround (another css code) that can centre the button so that it works on gmail?

Below is the code:

```
.button-td{
background:#FFA06A;
text-align:center;
position:relative !important;
}

.button-a{
background:#FFA06A;
padding:8px 25px;
font-size:16px;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
position:absolute !important;
text-align:center !important;
top:50% !important;
left:50% !important;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%) !important;
}

<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center-on-narrow" role="presentation" style="display:table !important;" mc:edit="imagewithcta">
<tr>
<td class="button-td">
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1" style="max-width:600px;" alt="photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1">

<a class="button-a" href="*|ARCHIVE3|*">
<span class="button-link">
READ MORE
</span>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: maybe wrap the a tag inside a div and then make the image as background image. Give some fixed height and then you can just align the button by adding the following style on the div parent: text-align:center

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas I know setting a background image has been causing problems within mailchimp where it doesn't allow the user to change the background image within the content block. I'm going to try your way but not setting the image as background image to see what happens

Comment: you can not bring the button over the image if it is not in an absolute position...

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas - Damn, So I can't set background image and I can't set absolute so kind of stuck

Answer (score 2):

HTML emails are evil, you get a really small subset of HTML to work with reliably across email clients. background images aren't even reliably supported across everything so you should code for fallbacks see here:

https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-background-images-in-email/

```css
.tablestyle {
  background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1');
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  background-size:cover; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.button-td {
  text-align:center;

}


.button-a{
background:#FFA06A;
padding:8px 25px;
font-size:16px;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;

}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center-on-narrow tablestyle" role="presentation"  mc:edit="imagewithcta">
<tr >
<td class="button-td">
<table width="100%" height="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><a class="button-a">TEST</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```